# Promise as a if condition

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm quite bad with JS promises and async and I face a problem about it.

First things first the simplified code:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    const data = event.data ? event.data.json() : {}
    if (isClientFocused()) {
        console.log('Don\'t need to show a notification.');
        return;
    }
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data)
    )
});

function isClientFocused() {
    return self.clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true
    })
        .then((windowClients) => {
            let clientIsFocused = false;
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                if (windowClient.focused) {
                    clientIsFocused = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return clientIsFocused;
        });
}
```

The concept is quite straight forward: my function `isClientFocused` return `true` or `false` depending on the situation and I want to use this value as a condition in my if in my event listener.

I precise that isClientFocused function works well and everytime return the result as expected, but when used in the if condition, it always log `Don't neet to show notification.`

I guess it's just an implementation problem but I'm a bit lost right now.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add async/await because isClientFocused() returns a promise and it's truthy and condition is always true. With the resolved value with `await` you get a proper logic.
Also you should call `event.waitUntil` immediately (sync):

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => event.waitUntil((async () => {
   if (await isClientFocused()) {
       console.log('Don\'t need to show a notification.');
       return;
   const data = event.data?.json() ?? {};
   return self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data)
})()));
```

I suggest to refactor isClientFocused() with async/await and use async/await as much as possible to avoid `then()`. Also you could use `Array::some()` instead of your loop.

In my experience `async/await` leads to less bugs and more readable and maintainable when async/await is learned.

It's just amazing when I refactor a buggy `then()` code to `async/await` the bugs disappeared automatically.

```
async function isClientFocused() {
    const windowClients = await self.clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true
    });
    return windowClients.some(windowClient => windowClient.focused);
}
```

Comment: I edited as you said and it seems that now the difference between focused or not works.

But when not focused I get an error:

serviceworker.js:39 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished and no extend lifetime promises are outstanding.

So it seems that if not focused, everything works welle but when focused it does not

Comment: @Tartempion34 i think it's not related, another issue

Comment: @Tartempion34 seems you can't use a promise here and should call waitUntil immediately. waitUntil is from which library?

Comment: from ExtendableEvent in service workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is wrote here :o
But it does not work now it does not do anything no console log no call to notfication :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254329/discussion-between-tartempion34-and-alexander-nenashev).

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi the link is useless. unless i'm explained when this approach fails i'm not jumping into the bandwagon with the flock

Comment: @Bergi there's no diferrence with using ’then’. the returned promise isn't used anywhere

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I'm not suggesting to us `.then()`. I'm suggesting to avoid `new Promise`, as that introduces the need for `try`/`catch` to handle errors correctly (which you initially forgot). Use `event.waitUntil((async () => { if (await isClientFocused()) return; const data = event.data?.json() ?? {}; await self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data); })());` - much simpler and less error-prone!

Comment: @Bergi now i see, looks not perfect (iife) but better, thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev If you don't like the IIFE, you can declare it as a named function or define a helper `const run = f => f()` and use `event.waitUntil(run(async () => { … }));`, still better than abusing `new Promise` for this purpose

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your answer but still doesn't do anything. Even added some log but stays empty like if nothing happened at al

Comment: @Bergi I don't know if it can help but Originaly I'm trying to implement the part "The Exception to the Rule" of this : https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/common-notification-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this, isClientFocused function is a Promise, when you call it, you have to wait for complete this function.

The code should look like this;

```js
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    const data = event.data ? event.data.json() : {}
    isClientFocused().then(res=>{
      if (res) {
          console.log('Don\'t need to show a notification.');
          return;
      }
      event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data))
    })
});
```

Note : Promise gives an output similar to this if you do not wait for a function to run ;

```js
{"_h": 0, "_i": 3, "_j": {"_h": 0, "_i": 1, "_j": 3, "_k": null}, "_k": null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it like that:

```js
async function isClientFocused() {
    const windowClients = await self.clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true
    });
    return windowClients.some(windowClient => windowClient.focused);
}

self.addEventListener('push', async (event) => {
    if (await isClientFocused()) {
        console.log("Don't need to show a notification.");
        return;
    }

    const data = event.data ? event.data.json() : {};
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data);
});
```

Thanks to @Bergi and @AlexanderNenashev for the help